# php is working from cli, but magento is not

Tags: php, magento, command-line-interface

I've managed to get php running within windows 10 command prompt by adding **;C:\xampp\php** to the Environment Variables. But I still cannot start magento commands.

I am opening a command prompt from my `magento/bin` folder and typing any magento command, but I get the "magento is not recognized as an internal or external..." error, so my magento install is still without images.

[image]

These are the [options](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/magento-2-cli/) I've been trying out.

What am I still missing?

Answer (score 0):

try running

```
php magento cache:flush
```

or

```
C:\xampp\php\php.exe magento cache:flush
```

Comment: I cannot run magento commands thru CLI.

I tried with php magento and php bin/magento. Neither worked.

Comment: go to your site dir before running the command with "cd C:\path to site\magento\" and run the commands

Comment: I was running them from the site's directory, and also the bin folder. Neither worked.

Comment: I"m running into the same issue as well with Windows 10 Magento 2.2 installed using Bitnami and with regular installed through xampp and same thing, Magento commands doesn't work regardless of where i installed Magento and where i have used the commands. Also most tutorials are referencing sudo as if everyone is using Linux or Macos

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in the Magento Forums.

I typed the full path and worked.

> php C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\bin\magento setup:static-content:deploy

Answer (score 0):

execute this command on your local php directory ex: C:\xampp\php

```
php C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\bin\magento cache:flush
```